# jquery show/hide element on multiple radio button selection

Tags: jquery, forms, show, show-hide

I'm very new to web development, if you can even call it that, especially jQuery and I've hit a brick wall with a jQuery.

What I have is a form(for selection purposes), and a series of Paypal buttons. The function I need to perform is a show/hide but only if a particular selection of three radio buttons has been selected. Each three combination selection is to show/hide a corresponding paypal button.

I can show/hide fine with a single form radio selection, but not for the combination.

You'll have to excuse my cabbage coding as I'm still only a beginner, the code could be alot more optimized, thankfully it's only a low traffic site/small market its going into.BIG kudos to anyone who can help me.

Have managed to hide all the buttons fine. Script below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    //Hide div w/id extra
         $("#button1,#button2,#button3,#button4,#button5,
             #button6,#button7,#button8,#button9,#button10,
             #button11, #button12, #button13, #button14,#button15,
             #button16,#button17,#button18,#button19,#button20,
              #button21,#button22,#button23,#button24,                 
              #button25,#button26,#button27").css("display","none");

});

</script>
```

Here is the form html

```
    <form action="order-lamb" method="post" id="order">
   <input type="hidden" name="pack" value="whole" />
   <div class="form-item leg option left2">
      <h3> Choose from the following Leg options</h3>
      <p>Choose what leg options you would like:</p>
      <label for="leg-one-of-each"><input type="radio" name="leg" value="each" id="leg-one-of-each" />1 x Carvery and 1 x Butterfly Legs</label>
      <p class="or">OR</p>
      <label for="leg-both-carvery"><input type="radio" name="leg" value="carvery" id="leg-both-carvery" />2 x Carvery Legs</label>
      <p class="or">OR</p>
      <label for="leg-both-butterfly"><input type="radio" name="leg" value="butterfly" id="leg-both-butterfly" /> 2 x Butterfly Legs</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-item loin option right2 ">
      <h3> Choose from the following Loin options:</h3>
      <p>Choose what loin options you would like:</p>
      <label for="loin-one-of-each"><input type="radio" name="loin" value="loin-each" id="loin-one-of-each" />1 x Nolsette Loin and 1 x Backstrap &amp; Tenderloin</label>
      <p class="or">OR</p>
      <label for="loin-both-nolsette"><input type="radio" name="loin" value="nolsette" id="loin-both-nolsette" />2 x Nolsette Loins </label>
      <p class="or">OR</p>
      <label for="loin-both-backstrap"><input type="radio" name="loin" value="backstrap-tenderloin" id="loin-both-backstrap" />2 x Backstrap &amp; Tenderloins </label>
   </div>
   <div class="cf"></div>
   <div class="form-item shoulder option left2">
      <h3>Choose from the following Shoulder options:</h3>
      <p>Choose what shoulder option you would like:</p>
      <label for="shoulder-one-of-each"><input type="radio" name="shoulder" value="shoulder-each" id="shoulder-one-of-each" /> 1 x Bone and Rolled and 1 x French Danish</label>
      <p class="or">OR</p>
      <label for="shoulder-both-bone-and-rolled"><input type="radio" name="shoulder" value="bone-and-rolled" id="shoulder-both-bone-and-rolled" />2 x Bone and Rolled</label>
      <p class="or">OR</p>
      <label for="shoulder-both-french-danish"><input type="radio" name="shoulder" value="french-danish" id="shoulder-both-french-danish" />2 x French Danish</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-item included right2">
      <h3>You will also get:</h3>
      <p>These are included:</p>
      <span class="choice selected">2 x Fully Frenched Racks </span>
      <p class="or">AND</p>
      <span class="choice selected">1 x Coastal Spring Lamb Mince Pack </span> </span>    
      <p class="or">AND</p>
      <span class="choice selected">1 x Coastal Spring Lamb Patty Pack</span> </span>
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="align-right" />
   <div class="form-item submit">
      <p class="error">You must select an option in each category.</p>
      <input type="image" name="submit" src="images/buttons-and-logos/awaiting-payment.png" id="submit" border="0" />
      <p class="paypal">You will receive a confirmation email when your payment has been processed via paypal. <br />Price includes freight and GST.<br /></p>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of a list of `id`s, you should give all of those buttons a `class` and use that instead.

Comment: What combinations are supposed to result in which buttons showing? Not really sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: i've just used the ids for now, theres three sets of three radio options, they're for ordering meat off a local farm, one set for  leg options, a second set for loin cut option and a third for a shoulder cut option. A customer is to click on a selection from each set of three, and depending on the combination the submit button is to direct them to the corresponding paypal checkout page.

Comment: And how abt the buttons..Where are they ??

Comment: At the moment the paypal buttons are just in a area at the bottom of my page, but it's not them I'm worried about, it's just the act of showing/hiding an element through a combination as opposed to single radio button selection. Would it be done through variables?

Comment: @KRyan yeah I got most of the below answer working, you'll see what I'm trying to do if you visit here http://infernodesign.co.nz/tempfiles/csl-dev/buy-online-half.php  The only issue now is that Once a combined selection is made, if I want to change my mind on the first or second option, it doesnt swap out. My Jquery code for this is a little horrible,  there must be a 'else' or something

http://jsfiddle.net/spikeyheadedfreak/WwQW5/

Answer (score 1):

first off you should make a class for those buttons which would make your code easier to keep clean and less effort on your part. It would go something like this.

In your button creation.

```
<input type="button" class="hideMe">
```

Then in a CSS file you would have as follows

```
.hideMe{
     display:none;
}
```

Or if you dont want a CSS file seperate you can also do as follows in your javascript section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     //Hide div w/id extra
     $(".hideMe").css("display","none");

});
</script>
```

Along those lines anyway.

Secondly, to answer your main question, you can always have a check on the last button to ensure all 3 are checked.

```
$('input:radio[name="yourRadioNameHere"]').change(function(){
       if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(radioButton2).is(':checked')  && $(radioButton2).is(':checked') ) {
         // Do whatever you need to do here
       }
});
```

I am sure there is a more elegant solution out there however I am tired at the moment and just about to finish up for the day lol. But that should work.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:
To get it working on all 3 checkboxes you would need to do 3 if statements. However to save repeating of code create a function to perform the checks for you. Eg

```
    function checkChecked(){
           if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(radioButton2).is(':checked')  && $(radioButton2).is(':checked') ) {
         // Do whatever you need to do here
       }
    }
```

You would then have 3 if statements that call this function. An example below.

```
       $('input:radio[name="yourRadioNameHere"]').change(function(){
       checkCheck();
});
```

As I said there are more then likely more elegant solutions out there but this will get what your looking for done.
For example I am pretty sure there are functions out there that will check if any check box is changed which would save you the 3 if statements. However I shall leave that google search to you :).

Hope the extra code helps.

Comment: cheers, i'm going wrong somewhere here 

$(document).ready(function(){ $('input:radio[name="shoulder-each"]').change( function(){ if ($(this).is(':checked') && $('#leg-one-of-each').is(':checked') && $('#loin-one-of-each').is(':checked') ) { $('#button1').show(); } }); @wirey

Comment: @spikeyheadedfreak if you could create a jsfiddle.net and replicate/explain what your issue is.  It would make it a lot easier to help you troubleshoot what you're doing wrong

Comment: @spikeyheadedfreak is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/taJ3w/1/   You were missing closing bracket and parentheses

Comment: @wirey Cheers, i fixed that bit, seem to have the show function going fine now, had to delete the previous comment as my boss had a word to me about sharing my development version. I seem to be having issues with the code thats been used to make the custom radio buttons, they're remaining in a "selected" state

Comment: @spikeyheadedfreak  I don't quite understand what you mean.  So the custom radio buttons will not change state?

Comment: @wirey Figured out the issue there.

Comment: @wirey So the Answer worked , BUT not for every option, one Combination of options will show and hide, but if I change the second or first out of the options, it will not change the button unless I change the third option. This isn't ideal as if a customer changes their mind in the selection process, it needs to swap out 
.example of what i'm doing here 
http://infernodesign.co.nz/tempfiles/csl-dev/buy-online-half.php

and a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/spikeyheadedfreak/WwQW5/, though im still getting the hand of that  Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi Spikey, that is because the if statement only covers one option. An alternative to this would be to do somthing like create a function that checks which of the boxs are checked and then make 3 if statments that call the function. I shall update my answer.

Comment: Code has been updated to reflect above problem. The reason it was not working for all options was because your if statement only covered one option. Whatever name you put into the radio button. There are functions out there that will detect a change in any checkbox instead of just a named one but I am sure you can find that yourself lol as I do not know off the top of my head.