# Jquery show hide on multiple radio buttons

Tags: jquery, forms, hide, show, show-hide

new to web development and have bitten off more than I can chew with this particular code.

I asked a question yesterday about it and have got it to work about 50% of the way  with the answer there [jquery show/hide element on multiple radio button selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680111/jquery-show-hide-element-on-multiple-radio-button-selection/)

what I'm trying to do is show/hide a paypal button depending on the radio selection,
so a customer will choose one option from category 1, one option from category 2, and a one option from category 3. The code I've got acts on the selection of the third option, checks what else has been checked and displays the paypal button relating to that selection.

all up I have 35 buttons, on this particular page I'm using 8 http://infernodesign.co.nz/tempfiles/csl-dev/buy-online-half.php  Here is a jsfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/spikeyheadedfreak/WwQW5/

The problem is after one three radio combination is made and the button related to it shows up, if i change either of the first two choices out of the three it won't changed the button, so if a customer changes their mind after clicking the third radio button they can't.

heres an example of  the jquery i've used, be nice, I'm new to this haha

```
      $('input:radio[value="Bone-and-Rolled-half"]').change(
  function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked') && $('#leg-one-carvery').is(':checked')  && $('#loin-one-nolsette').is(':checked') ) {
            $('#submit,#button29,#button30,#button31,#button32,#button33,#button34,#button35').hide();
     $('#button28').show();

   }

   });  


  $('input:radio[value="French-Danish-half"]').change(
  function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked') && $('#leg-one-carvery').is(':checked')  && $('#loin-one-nolsette').is(':checked') ) {
             $('#submit,#button28,#button30,#button31,#button32,#button33,#button34,#button35').hide();
     $('#button29').show();

   }

   });  



          $('input:radio[value="Bone-and-Rolled-half"]').change(
  function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked') && $('#leg-one-carvery').is(':checked')  && $('#loin-one-backstrap').is(':checked') ) {
            $('#submit,#button28,#button29,#button31,#button32,#button33,#button34,#button35').hide();
     $('#button30').show();

   }

   });  


  $('input:radio[value="French-Danish-half"]').change(
  function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked') && $('#leg-one-carvery').is(':checked')  && $('#loin-one-backstrap').is(':checked') ) {
             $('#submit,#button28,#button29,#button30,#button32,#button33,#button34,#button35').hide();
     $('#button31').show();

   }

   });  





          $('input:radio[value="Bone-and-Rolled-half"]').change(
  function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked') && $('#leg-one-butterfly').is(':checked')  && $('#loin-one-nolsette').is(':checked') ) {
            $('#submit,#button28,#button29,#button30,#button31,#button33,#button34,#button35').hide();
     $('#button32').show();

   }

   });  


  $('input:radio[value="French-Danish-half"]').change(
  function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked') && $('#leg-one-butterfly').is(':checked')  && $('#loin-one-nolsette').is(':checked') ) {
             $('#submit,#button28,#button29,#button30,#button31,#button32,#button34,#button35').hide();
     $('#button33').show();

   }

   });  

          $('input:radio[value="Bone-and-Rolled-half"]').change(
  function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked') && $('#leg-one-butterfly').is(':checked')  && $('#loin-one-backstrap').is(':checked') ) {
            $('#submit,#button28,#button29,#button30,#button31,#button32,#button33,#button35').hide();
     $('#button34').show();

   }

   });  


  $('input:radio[value="French-Danish-half"]').change(
  function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked') && $('#leg-one-butterfly').is(':checked')  && $('#loin-one-backstrap').is(':checked') ) {
             $('#submit,#button28,#button29,#button30,#button31,#button32,#button33,#button34').hide();
     $('#button35').show();

   }

   });
```